# Converting a .jsx file using Tailwindcss Typescript error

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I copy an example code from the Tailwind sight.  When I changed the file to a .tsx I get an error with the className.

Do I need to define a type

What do I need to do to make the error go away?

Binding element 'className' implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
import clsx from 'clsx'

export function Container({ className, ...props }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={clsx('mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8', className)}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: you need to provide types for props, so try ```Container({ className, ...props }: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>)```

Answer (score 1):

```
import clsx from 'clsx'

interface ContainerProps {
    className: string
}

export function Container({ className, ...props }: ContainerProps) {
    return <div className={clsx('mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8', className)} {...props} />
}
```